# Center widgets with same distance to each other/ to window border tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, center

When I put the widgets directly in the root window, I can use grid_columnconfigure
but as u can see in the picture, the distance between one to another widget is twice as to boarder, I want that also the same distance too. And actually, it should not be put in root but in a Frame/ LabelFrame but there is not even the grid_columnconfigure method possible, why is that so?

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        parent.grid_columnconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1)

        self.label1 = tk.Label(root, text="test", bg="green").grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.label2 = tk.Label(root, text="test", bg="green").grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.label3 = tk.Label(root, text="test", bg="green").grid(row=0, column=2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.state("zoomed")
    MainApplication(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: Sample Display]

Comment: _"but there is not even the grid_columnconfigure method possible, why is that so?"_ - why do you think it's not possible? Have you tried it?

Comment: For your case, you need to put the text in columns 1,3,5 and set `weight=1` on columns 0,2,4,6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@*Bryan Oakley* sure I tried it, I tried it for hours but don’t get it to run but think I found my error now

I wrote

```
frame0 = tk.Label(parent).pack(fill="x")
```

instead of

```
frame0 = tk.Label(parent)
frame0.pack(fill="x")
```

but don’t understand why the first one doesn’t work in that case

@*acw1668* ty very very much, that it is, I don’t think of it it’s possible to give an empty column a weight

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent


        frame0 = tk.Label(parent)
        frame0.pack(fill="x")

        frame0.grid_columnconfigure((0, 2, 4, 6), weight=1)



        self.label1 = tk.Label(frame0, text="test", bg="green").grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.label2 = tk.Label(frame0, text="test", bg="green").grid(row=0, column=3)
        self.label3 = tk.Label(frame0, text="test", bg="green").grid(row=0, column=5)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.state("zoomed")
    MainApplication(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you put the three labels inside another label (`frame0`), but not `self`?